# Share information between two static classes in Actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, class, singleton

I have a complex situation that I need to resolve becouse this is out of my boundaries.

I create:

- **Game:** Instance from the **Class A** ( static class built with a singleton pattern )
- **Question:** Instance from the **Class B** ( static class built with a singleton pattern, this is created and deleted each time that the user choose an option from the Class A instance )
- **Score:** Instance from the **Class C** ( public function )

The problem is that the **Score** instance is created in the **Game** instance because the score is shown all the time. **Question** instance has the result of each question depending on the user selection so, I need to know this because I've all the code but only remains this part so It's very difficult to paste here:

is there any way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Why are you creating an instance of the Class C as Score? Is it containing only one variable? You should make a public variable in the game for tracking the score.

Comment: You mean that should I create a public class in the Main class?

Answer (score 0):

You should:

```
//document class
package 
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class DocumentClass extends Sprite 
    {
        public static var GAME;
        public function DocumentClass() {
            addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        }
        private function init(e:Event){
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
            GAME = new Game();
        }
    }
}
//Game class
package 
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class Game extends Sprite 
    {
        public var score:int;
        public function Game() {
            addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        }
        private function init(e:Event){
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
            //some functions/listeners & variable settings.
            score = 0;
        }
        private function someFunction() {
            stage.addChild(new HighscoreTable(score));//passing score to the highscore table...
        }
    }
}
```

Static classes (only contains static variables & functions without constructor) are often useless.. try to combine it with other "tricks".

Comment: In this case where is applied the unique instance of the game? I mean the game class should be unique to kill it when the game is finished

Comment: You can kill the Game instance in the someFunction function in the Game class with this: Main.GAME = null;
If the Game is displayed somehow, then remove the children first, then the Game, and then you can null it!